# Ignore a nunit test based on the data that is loaded in TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nunit

I would like to ignore a test based on the input given to the test , I searched around and found couple of solutions,They are as follows

```
Assert.Ignore();
Assert.Inconclusive();
```

But what i need is it should ignore only when i passed the true value something like

```
Assert.Ignore(true);
```

I did achieve what i wanted using the conditional statement like the following

```
if(ignoreTheTest)
{
Assert.Ignore();
}
```

i feel some what this is not best way of doing this , i want to know if there was a better way doing it.Thank you in advance :).I am just starting out ,sorry with the novice que

Comment: If your doing this your unit tests are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used this, but if your complaint is about the if-statement that you have to write every time I would suggest you to extract the code into a method::

```
public static void Assert(Func<bool> cond, string message = "")
{
    if(cond())
    {
        Assert.Ignore(message);
    }
}
```